# Using WHERE Clause SQLite database in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my code:

```
    public int getIdMotChuDe(String tenChuDe) {
            int IDChuDe = 0;
            try
            {
                Cursor c = null;
                c = database.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT ChuDeID FROM DanhSachChuDe WHERE TenChuDe = ?"
                     , new String[] {tenChuDe});
                c.moveToFirst();
                IDChuDe = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ChuDeID"));
                c.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return IDChuDe;
        }
```

I'm trying to get `ChuDeID` from `DanhSachChuDe` table with condition in WHERE clause. But i don't know why this function always return `0`.
Help me please. Thanks! Sorry because my english.

Comment: did you `close()` your `database` somewhere else, before using its `rawQuery`?

Comment: check the contents of your LogCat

Comment: Debug the method it is returning 0 because you have initialised it to 0. Check the column names and confirm there are values in database for that column

Comment: Hi Kesh. Everything is correct. But I don't know why it's not work.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because an `Exception` is being thrown. The code you are using is not correctly checking the state of your `Cursor` - it attempts to `moveToFirst()` before any checking too see if the object is not `null`.

Your code also assumes a result is *always* returned. This is bad practise, and should be avoided. A much safer and more common solution is the following:

```
if (cursor != null) {
    // If the cursor has results, move the cursor to first row
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // YOUR METHODS HERE
            // then move to next row
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: `rawQuery()` *never* returns `null`.

Comment: hello Ed.Thanks for rep. I'm trying to change my function follow your code. but it's not work.

Comment: Have you checked your LogCat to see if an Exception is being thrown?